# I'll find out the date of the next few days

Tags: c#, datetime, persian-calendar

Hello friends I had a question
For example today
06/24/2019. What code should I use if I want to find the date of the next 20 days?

Comment: date.AddDays(20);

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you tried anything to solve your problem? People love to see your effort before they try to solve your problem. Do you wanna get only 20th day from now or wanna get all 20 days from now? It would be better to read [FAQ] and [ask] couple of times as well.

Comment: My dear friend did not answer. I visited the page you introduced. But I did not answer

Answer (score 2):

```
var d = DateTime.Now().AddDays(20);
```